# Getting the actual jsp line number from a stack trace line number?

Tags: java, debugging, jsp, tomcat

Here is the stacktrace:

```
...
org.apache.jsp.showcustomer_jsp._jspService(showcustomer_jsp.java:128)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(Unknown Source)
```

This is what I do:

1. Get the line number from the stacktrace, in this case 128.
2. Find the `showcustomer_jsp.java` file (and it isn't exactly obvious to look in `/var/run/tomcat-6/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp`).
3. Open it and go to line 128.
4. Now, search the `.jsp` file for the whatever you found on line 128 in the `_jsp.java` file.
5. Boom! You're done!

Please, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Didn't even know you could do that. +1

Answer (score 5):

I have found this [page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_can_I_debug_with_the_Java_source_that_Tomcat_creates_for_a_JSP.3F) on Eclipse WTP FAQ which explain how to configure Eclipse so that you can go to the generated java code clicking on the stacktrace.

Comment: +1, but still - this will bring you to generated java code only, not original JSP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. The JSP file is compiled into a servlet, and is not run directly. As the exception is thrown from this servlet, the line you have in the stack trace is the one from the class. The original line in the JSP is lost at this point.

Usually it is best to avoid writing code or throwing exceptions from a jsp, and encapsulate your logic in servlets and JSP tags, and use JSTL for control flow (if, forEach, etc.)

Comment: WebLogic had a really nice feature in pre-WL10 versions: it would write a comment into the generated Java file showing the source JSP line number. Even if your logic is encapsulated in a taglib, it's nice to see which invocation threw.

Comment: And a quick look at the Jasper sources seems to indicate that it processes JSP files as a token stream, without knowledge of line numbers. So the answer is no.

Comment: The IDE has all the data to compute the original line number. Perhaps someone could write an IntelliJ plugin that does the job.

Comment: About JSTL: I'm not a fan of writing code as XML. It breaks the KISS principle.

Comment: You can use other templating engines, such as velocity or freemarker

Comment: what were the JSP designers thinking? The ability to go to the line number is very important. I spend more of my time guessing the line number in a JSP exception than actual coding. Also, I don't use eclipse, so the answer to use eclipse is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used to program in Lex and Yacc which would generate C code, and you could enable #line pre-processor directives for debugging.  When something happened in generated c code, then the IDE was smart enough to open the corresponding lex or yacc file, and not the generated c code.  Surly