# Find which line in translated JSP source maps to which line in JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to locate where an exception occurs in a JSP file.

I have following stacktrace on my console:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code '' for locale 'en'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.SERVICE.myJspFile_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f4(myJspFile_jsp.java:1293)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.SERVICE.myJspFile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f1(myJspFile_jsp.java:1260)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.SERVICE.myJspFile_jsp._jspService(myJspFile_jsp.java:319)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
```

This tells me that exception is at line 319 in translated JSP file when processing a custom tag.

I open translate JSP source:

```
}
            out.write("\n");
            out.write("            </td>\n");
            out.write("            <td class=\"data\">&nbsp;</td>\n");
            out.write("            <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">\n");
            out.write("            </td>\n");
            out.write("        </tr>\n");
            out.write("        <tr>\n");
            out.write("            <td class=\"label\" width=\"200px;\">");
            if (_jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f1(_jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0, _jspx_page_context, _jspx_push_body_count_form_005fform_005f0))
              return;
            out.write("</td>\n");
            out.write("            <td class=\"data\">");
            if (_jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(_jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0, _jspx_page_context, _jspx_push_body_count_form_005fform_005f0))
              return;
            out.write("</td>\n");
            out.write("            <td class=\"data\">&nbsp;</td>\n");
            out.write("            <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">\n");
            out.write("            </td>\n");
            out.write("        </tr>\n");
            out.write("        <tr>\n");
            out.write("            <td class=\"label\" width=\"200px;\">");
            if (_jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f2(_jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0, _jspx_page_context, _jspx_push_body_count_form_005fform_005f0))
              return;
```

Line 319 is:

```
    if (_jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f1(_jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0, _jspx_page_context, _jspx_push_body_count_form_005fform_005f0))
```

**How do I go from this line to the line in JSP file?**

One idea off top of my head would be to translate JSP verbosely in some way, so that translated JSP file has comments to assist debugging. (Don't know if there's such a thing as verbose JSP translation) Something like:

```
out.write("            <td class=\"data\">&nbsp;</td>\n"); //myJspFile:57
out.write("            <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">\n"); //myJspFile:58
out.write("            </td>\n"); //myJspFile:59
```

**Edit (Clarifications):**
The actual cause of error is irrelevant as the objective is to trace the location of exception.

Comment: @jmail and this edit is rolledback...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304776/getting-the-actual-jsp-line-number-from-a-stack-trace-line-number